# jquery calculate html values next to checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

My head is not thinking right today. Could any of you help? =)
Only checked int values in second column need to be calculated and alerted in sum.

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr><td>Product Name</td><td>Price $</td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox"> Product 1</td><td>200</td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox"> Product 2</td><td>300</td></tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('input').change(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input:checked").each(function(){
      sum += parseInt($("input:checked").closest('td').next().html());
    });
    alert(sum);
  });
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you should be using `$(this)` inside the `.each()` to find the closest `<td>` to the currently selected checkbox in the loop.

```
  // Bind to all checkboxes...
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input:checked").each(function(){
      // Use $(this) here
      sum += parseInt($(this).closest('td').next().html(), 10);
      // Always use the optional radix to parseInt() -----^^^^^
    });
    alert(sum);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should drink less wine while programming.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's better none or more.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).closest('td').next().text(), 10);
    });
    alert(sum);
});
```

You need to listen for the `change` event on *all* checkboxes, not only those `:checked`. Also, be sure to pass the `radix` parameter to `parseInt`. Finally, `this` will refer to the item being evaluated in the `each` function.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/38AeT/